# How to programmatically add DocString when attribute definition is used in python

Tags: python, attributes, docstring

I have a template class, which is supposed to be used as a template class for various classes to check values assigned to attributes. It mostly does what it needs to do, but I have not managed to set the Docstrings to the attributes. An extremely simplified version of the class looks like this:

```py
class CreateAttribute:
    def __init__(self, value, doc):
        self.value = value
        self.__doc__ = doc
        
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return self.value


class Example:
    attribute_1 = CreateAttribute(1.4, 'explanation for attribute_1')


ex = Example()

print(ex.attribute_1.__doc__)
```

This gives:

```py
'Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.'
```

And as you can see, the Docstring is that of `int` and not `explanation for attribute_1`. I understand why this is happening, but I don't have a solution to make it print the Docstring I set.

Comment: by removing the `__get__` it works

Comment: ok but I need the value as well, i.e. `ex.attribute_1` should indeed return 1.4 in this example.